# Laravel 5.2 detect specific view/controller in blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i have a parent layout in resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>
    <!-- JavaScripts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    {{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .fa-btn {
            margin-right: 6px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    Laravel
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/addthreadhtml') }}">Add thread</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    @yield('content')


</body>
</html>
```

i want to include a js in header  using if statement
- if addThreadForm.blade.php loaded into the content section

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that

after `<style>` tag add following

`@yield('header_scripts')`

then in the `addThreadForm.blade.php` file add your script within `section`

```
@section('header_scripts')
<script> alert('hi') </script>
@stop
```

This will execute only when `addThreadForm.blade.php` loaded

Answer (score 0):

@Mifas's answer is good, but it won't work if you intend to have other files also add scripts to the header. Laravel 5.2 has a nifty new feature in Blade called Stacks for this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#stacks

In `addThreadForm.blade.php`:

```
@push('scripts')
  <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endpush
```

and in your layout:

```
@stack('scripts')
```

This lets multiple Blade templates push to the stack, and then when the layout is rendered all of their various contributions will be combined and output.